# Having Trouble with a First Time Installation of PostgreSQL 14.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, apt, postgresql-14

I've been having a bit of trouble trying to install PostgreSQL 14 for the first time.

I would like to apologize in advance if this question has been asked in the manner that I am about to ask it, but I do not think it has.  If it has been, please direct me to the appropriate location!

I've done a fair amount of Googling on the matter, and all the information that I find seems to be rather fragmented, or I end up following a spaghetti trail of hyperlinks (*a la*-do-this-and-follow-this-other-link-with-**more-information-than-you-need**-to-understand-this-other-required-portion).
Personally, I don't want to jump around to 50 different locations on the web to *try* and conjure up a piecemeal solution that I **believe** works, only to be proven wrong later. I want to know what to do and **why** it works.  I've tried reading the documentation, and have given up on it, because to me, it seems to assume that the server *has already been set up* by a database administrator.

Instead of articulating my problem directly (as I seem to be having more trouble than I would like by trying to do so), I believe it would be easier to articulate my problem *indirectly* by stating what my ***expectations*** would be **after** installing PostgreSQL for the first time.

So to start, I will mention that I'm running **Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS**, and am installing **PostgreSQL 14.1** with the following command:

```
sudo apt install postgresql-14
```

**Before continuing,** I would like to add a side note in advance, that I **do not** want suggestions for an alternative OS or install method.  I just want to be able to get "up and running" in a common-sense fashion from this exact point.

Moving on, I know that the aforementioned command creates a *nix user called `postgres`.

From here, I can now indirectly state my problem using an outline of what my goals and expectations are immediately after installing the software via that command.

- **After** installing PostgreSQL via `apt`, these are my expected goals:

  - I want **any** client to be able to connect to the database server from any computer where a route exists from the client to the server.

    - **For the sake of simplicity with these stated goals**, when it is directly or implicitly stated that I am trying to connect a client to the database server, I am making the assumption that the client is able to, at a minimum, `ping` the machine that the server is running on, and vice versa.
    - For now, I'm not completely worried about the database being accessible from the public Internet.
    - I expect to be able to access the database from any computer on my LAN, whether it is an actual LAN, or some sort of logical LAN (like a WAN or a VPN).
  - If I change the PostgreSQL password of the **postgres** user, I expect that any client logging into the database  server via the **postgres** user will require the password.

    - This means if I want to change the password to **some_password** via `\password postgres` or `ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'some_password';` *(I am assuming this is how you change the login password of a PostgreSQL user)*, then...

      - I expect running `psql [-h host] -U postgres -W` from **any** host...

        - That when I am prompted to enter the password...

          - I can **only** log in by entering the exact password of **some_password**.
          - Entering any other arbitrary text for the password should not allow me to log in.

            - I am adding this as a requirement because previous install attempts have shown me that this is NOT the case.
    - I expect to be able to create a PostgreSQL user account other than **postgres** (e.g. **db_user**) *with* a password and have it be subject to the same requirements as the **postgres** user.

      - i.e. once the new account is given permission to log in, the same common-sense login requirements to log in **must** be imposed, i.e. you can't get in if you don't have the correct username/password combination.

**If the process to achieve the aforementioned can be explained in such a way that it can be understood with minimal mental friction, I would be extremely grateful.**

Feel free to assume that my knowledge is on par with that of a undergraduate CS student who just completed their first year of university, who also understands Linux filesystems and basic computer networking.  I just want the answer to be as accessible to as many people as possible, as I am sure I'm not the only person who has struggled with installing PostgreSQL, in spite of having a power user's level of computer literacy.

Comment: How did you get here to start with?  Ubuntu 18.04 runs PostgreSQL 10, not 14, out of its default repository.  If you are not willing to change your install method in any way, then you would not be running 14 in the first place.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo apt install postgresql
2. sudo -u postgres psql

   - Set a password for this user with \password or the other method you mention
3. sudo vi /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf

   - Make the only uncommented nonblank line in this file be `host all all all md5`
4. sudo vi /etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf

   - uncomment listen_addresses line and set it to '*'
5. sudo service postgresql restart

When you make a new user, you should also make a new database which has the same spelling as the user does.  Otherwise you will need to specify the database name when you try to log in with psql -U, such as `psql -U newname -d postgres -h[hhh]`.   Should you actually be running 14 not 10, then you will need to change the paths of the config files you need to edit accordingly.